# Cordova Android Auto-Selects Select Element

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, usability

I'm using Cordova to facilitate a "native" iOS/Android app. Angular with Ionic is powering the view. I have a multi-step form that is using ng-show to mock the "wizard" aspect of the form. Upon clicking next from the previous step, the newly revealed "step" contains a select element which Android is selecting automatically, therefor causing some usability issues / confusion (the select options are displayed before the user has a chance to even see what's going on underneath).

This behavior is not consistent, though it happens more often than not. Simply toggling between "steps" may open the select options 4 out of 5 times one time but only 2 out of 5 times the next. There is nothing in the underlying Angular framework that is causing this behavior as far as I can tell.

Is there something within the Android OS that is attempting to select the select element? If so, how can this behavior be disabled?

This issue persists regardless of whether or not Angular's ng-options is used.

In this particular case, the select element is not the first nor last input element on the screen.

I have tried to divert the attention to the first input element (a text input) by forcing the focus to that element. The select box is being selected by Android.

iOS, Firefox, Chrome, Safari do not have this issue. We have tested on multiple Android devices with the same issue rearing its head on each.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the HTML definition of your "select" element you can remove the autofocus like this:

```
<select autofocus="">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Ref:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/select.html
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_autofocus.asp

Comment: Unfortunately, adding autofocus="" was not enough to convince the Android OS from assuming I'm extremely eager to select an option.